# How to structure a method that takes in a method as a parameter and also arguments to that method

Tags: python-3.x

I have this method `generate_csv` that looks like this:

```py
def generate_csv(
    headers: list[str],
    rows: list[dict[str, Any]],
    transformation_func: Callable[[dict[str, Any]], list[Any]] = _default_transformation,
):
    csv_string: str
    with io.StringIO() as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)

        writer.writerow(headers)
        for row in rows:
            transformed_row = transformation_func(row)

            writer.writerow(transformed_row)
        return output.getvalue()

def _default_transformation(row: dict[str, Any]):
    return list(row.values())
```

Essentially takes a list of dicts as rows and converts it to a CSV. I want to be able to allow for transformations of the rows, so I allow for a `transformation_func` to be supplied which will take a row and spit out a list.

What I'm not sure of is the best way to pass parameters to this `transformation_func` that are unique to only that function.

For example, lets say I have a mapping of customer ids to their lifetime spend in my app. I would have something like the following

```
def _transform_customer_data(row: dict[str, Any], id_to_spend: dict[int, float]):
   return [
      row['id'],
      row['name'],
      id_to_spend[row['id']]
   ]

csv_string = generate_csv(
   ["id", "name", "lifetime_spend"],
   rows,
   _transform_customer_data
)
```

Since each transformation function potentially has it's own parameters, what is the best way to set this up so I can pass something like `id_to_spend` through `generate_csv` and into the defined transformation function?